# Can you restore old stalls in the Festival Plaza?

Tags: pokemon-sun-moon

So far I've been offered to host several stalls, though the mechanic seems slightly confusing.

The player is not informed what the stall may do/sell beyond what the name implies. Additionally, to host a new stall, an old stall must be removed. There is an NPC that will allow you to rearrange active stalls though I have not found a way to choose from stalls I have replaced.

Is there any way to restore old stalls or are they lost forever once you replace them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to a post in [this thread](https://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/187276-pokemon-sun/74583548), you are able to get stalls that you've replaced starting at level 8:

> They're gone for good when you swap them, technically, but at level 8 you gain the ability to ask your guests if they "know any good facilities", and they'll recommend you a shop that they have in their plaza. You can then buy that shop for anywhere from 50FC to... idk 200FC? All the ones I've seen so far are 50 or 100 XP
>
> So basically at lvl 8 you can run around your plaza asking everyone about facilities to find ones you want~

Comment: I now have this functionality and can add facilities in this way, though it's not an intuitive system. Seems like an odd design choice...